# MacBook seems to update automatically while put to sleep despite update settings disabled

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update, ventura, auto-update

Last week I had shown an open update (there was an update listed under "System Settings > General > Software Update") but all update settings were already disabled:

[image: Update settings]

When I opened the MacBook today, it showed me a window with new features and the "Software Update" section said the "Mac is up to date".

```
# softwareupdate --history | head
Display Name                                       Version    Date                  
------------                                       -------    ----                  
macOS Ventura 13.2.1                               13.2.1     13.03.2023, 02:47:54
```

Update history shows the update was done on Monday, the automatic updates were disabled 2 weeks prior to that date.

**1. Why are the disabled options not working (particularly "Install macOS updates")?**

**2. How do I prevent MacBook from ever updating anything automatically?**

Comment: Can you describe what "I had shown an open update" means? What exactly did you see?  What version of Ventura are you on now? And frankly, given the state of Ventura, I'd welcome every update I could get. There's certainly no reason not to install security updates.

Comment: Updated the question, update was listed under "Software Update". Ventura version 13.2.1 (22D68). This question is about STOPING auto updates, not the usefulness of security updates!

Comment: We downvote without saying whats wrong about the question?

Comment: Are you certain an update was applied *after* you disabled updates or was an update applied and you just didn’t notice prior to disabling?

Comment: Also, issue the command `softwareupdate —history | head`. Do the latest updates occur before or after you disabling updates? (There are two dashes for the history flag; website makes it look like one)

Comment: @Allan Add the output in the question, update was done on monday. At that point the setting was already disabled, I checked them last time on Sunday before the Monday update.

Comment: @Allan So to be clear, the update was applied AFTER all update settings were already disabled, this is the reason I asked the question here.

Comment: [Ventura was released 13-Feb](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222) which is approximately 2 weeks ***prior*** to your stated disabling of updates.  It’s entirely plausible that the update was in process and only completed when your Mac was rebooted last.  Wait for the next update to see if it still gets applied.